# access ActiveRecord Has Many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a model which has a lot of associations. What I need to do is to check whether one of those associations is not present or all of them are set correctly.

To do so, I created an array which includes all of those needs-to-be-checked fields. And created a loop through each element, but the case is that I can not access has_many related attributes with `read_attribute` method. It basically returns nil whenever I try to access has many associated fields.

What I am trying to do, I can access all related objects via `car.drivers` but I can not access the same object with `car.read_attribute(:drivers)` (because some of them are attributes and some are relations)

I think it's the behavior of `read_attribute`, so what should I use to access any (attribute or relation) on ActiveRecord object?

Regarding to the comments, it looks like no one understand what I am trying to do. I want to access the relations of one ActiveRecord object such like;

```
RELATIONS.each do |relation|
   puts "#{relation} exists" if @object.relation.present?
end
```

What I do not know about this, is there any method that I can access the related objects with their string typed name. Similar to, `@object.read_attribute(:attribute_name)` In that way I can create a for loop, but for relations not for the attributes

Comment: Drivers is not an attribute of car. It's a relationship. I didn't get what you are trying to do.

Comment: I neither understood your doubt. please, paste some code sample

Comment: @OfficeYA I did, please check it out

Comment: What @Morris is telling you is that your expectation that `read_attribute` would work on an assocations is completely baseless. Attributes are stored in a hash like stucture and `read_attribute` gets that key from the hash. Assocations on the other hand are implemented as method where calling the method will create a SQL query to get the records unless they are already loaded.

Comment: What you may be looking for is `where.associated(relation_name)` - but the rest of code makes zero sense - the fact that you're using a constant is very confusing. https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-adds-where-associated-to-check-association-presence

Comment: @max I already understood that attributes are hash of key-value pairs and do not include relations, since relations can be accessed through methods within the name declared on has_many relation definition; I need a method to also access to the relations. something like; @object.read_relation(:relation_name) I need it because I will create a loop through all of the relations, so object.relation_name is not a way that I can use (relation_name will be iterated such like, relation1 relation2 etc.. ) To do so I think about eval() function but I think there is more Ruby way exists

Comment: Its very unclear what or why you're trying to do this - you can call any method dynamically in ruby with `send`, `call` and `public_send`. Also the method above takes the name as a parameter.

Comment: Okay I found my way to solve this, can check out my accepted answer to see what I actually meant and was looking for

Comment: @max yes that is what I was looking for actually, I lost myself looking for something similar to read_**** but yes! the answer is dynamical method calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do so, I used dynamical method call. Below is an example of showing it

```
RELATIONS.each do |relation|
   puts "#{relation} exists" unless @object.send('relation').nil?
end
```

Comment: Baran, please post more code so I get the whole picture, especially your model definitions (or something I can recreate to test against). I am just about to leave office, but, tomorrow when I get back I will take a look.